# In what circumstances recent apps are killed by Android other than a need for resource?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, kill-process

One of the main reasons that all we know is that *Android* may need some memory resources or battery saving and decide to do this. BUT what I want to know is:

is there anything else, like time limit, which may make *Android* kill your process? or anything else?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything else like time limit which may make android kill your process? or anything else?

It's meaningless for the system to kill a process recently important to user by a reason other than reclaiming system resources.

**But** long running processes (~ 30 minutes which may vary with OS versions) may either

- [be downgraded in their "importance"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html) so that their "chances" to be killed by the system increase
- or get [their task cleared](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always), i.e. *"the system clears a task (removes all activities from the stack above the root activity) in certain situations when the user re-selects that task from the home screen. Typically, this is done if the user hasn't visited the task for a certain amount of time, such as 30 minutes."* ***Note that clearing a task is not same as killing an app process***!

P.S. As to your assumption, for a device without *"lack of resource or anything"*, you may ([or may not!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847342/does-automatic-task-clearing-occur-in-modern-versions-of-android)) observe the task clearing after not visiting the app for ~30 minutes.

Comment: yes this sounds silly to me too but i observe that some times the main activity life cycle starts from onCreate again returning from recent apps while that has been the most recent app. and the device im observing is a huge memory. what causes this ? this is unpredictable :/

Comment: i mean the first activity that comes up. and the question is about recent applications. if my application is in the recent applications list for 30 minutes and device doesnt need any resource like memory or battery would android kill my process just becuase of being in the list for a long time ?

Comment: look i may confuse you. my question may even be wrong. i want to know if  the `onCreate` of my main activity will be called again only after leaving the device for a portion of time ? assume there isnt any lack of resource or anything.
its kinda a question about application and activity life cycle and android behaviour at the same time.

Comment: @Amir Ziarati, I thought at first place, that the official documentation I provided would be enough :)... I'll let you know If I find something new. But regarding 30-mins-task-clearing you could test it on your own: the system should finish each `Activity` (call `onDestroy()`) except the root one after the time. Just log each `onDestroy()`.

Comment: @Amir Ziarati, I ran into an interesting Q (added the link to the P.S. part) regarding the system behavior... Beside logging `onDestroy()` you could just run the app and look at its PID. If after 30 mins it changes - the system killed the process, not cleared its task.